# Highlighting repetitions in rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to find a way of **finding repetitions in a whole set of rows** and having much difficulty. I'm no Excel expert. I have looked at many formulas on finding duplicates in columns but am unable to transpose those to finding repetitions in rows only. I'll explain. See diagram:

[image]

In essence I would like to have highlighted the same words in rows if repeated three times (and in different colours by different keywords).

As you can see this would quickly enable finding those key positions where I get three 'FIRED' and three 'LONG' flash up coincidentally in the same row, with much less effort.

Comment: Is it restricted to these three words, SHORT, LONG and Fired, or could there be more? Are they always next to each other as shown?

Answer (score 2):

A CF formula rule of:

```
=OR(AND(A1=B1,A1=C1),AND(B1=C1,B1=D1),AND(C1=D1,C1=E1))
```

applied to Columns C:H should find any three consecutive cells in a row where the value is the same.

For filling with different colours each colour would require a separate rule, for example:

```
=OR(AND(A1=B1,A1=C1,A1="Fired"),AND(B1=C1,B1=D1,B1="Fired"),AND(C1=D1,C1=E1,C1="Fired"))
```

should work for pale blue:

[image: SO31536207 example]

Comment: It took me a while to understand this - I can see now that it tests for column C matching either (a) col A&B, (b) col B&D (c) col D&E. So the formula is absolutely correct as long as you start conditional formatting  in cell C1 and as the headers in row 1 are all different it won't highlight them +1

Comment: No problem. Only other comment, you could add AND(...C1<>"" ) if you wanted to avoid highlighting empty cells but your second formula would cover that anyway.

Comment: I've tested the formulas and they're not working for me in CF. Can others try and see if they work? See/download test file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6yzjOpAzvJ7THNyd2VULWxPWnc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Well, what's actually happening for me is that the first 'fired' is being highlighted if there are three consecutive 'fired's but not all three.